# Error converting data type SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have an object with the following data:

```
{
    "ItemID": "0000000",
    "ConsignmentID": "0000000",
    "CountryCreateDate": "24/05/2013 3:20:02 a.m.",
    "Reference": "00000000",
    "Packaging": "0",
    "Weight": "0",
    "WeightCubic": "0",
    "Length": "0",
    "Width": "0",
    "Height": "0",
    "seqNumber": "0",
    "DatePrinted": "",
    "ad_Excess": "0",
    "Price_Cost": "",
    "Price_Other": "",
    "Price_OtherTypeID": "",
    "FailedReason": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "packedInCustomID": "",
    "UpdateDateUTC": "6/06/2013 9:55:05 p.m.",
    "PrintedByCustomerUserID": ""
}
```

This is inserted directly into a SQL Server CE database using `ExecuteNonQuery`, nothing is wrong with that or the way its being inserted and has been tested and used a lot.

When inserting this data into a table with the following schema I get the error:

> There was a syntax error while converting from one data type to another. [ Expression =  ]

[image]

I've looked over and over the data and there seems to be nothing out of place. Should I be converting the dates or something? Everything is being inserted as type `NVarChar` as they are all strings.

The date format is also in the format `d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt`

The insert query I use is:

```
INSERT INTO example
(
    ItemID, 
    ConsignmentID, 
    CountryCreateDate, 
    Reference, 
    Packaging, 
    Weight, 
    WeightCubic, 
    Length, 
    Width, 
    Height, 
    seqNumber, 
    DatePrinted, 
    ad_Excess, 
    Price_Cost, 
    Price_Other, 
    Price_OtherTypeID, 
    FailedReason, 
    PackedInCustomID, 
    UpdateDateUTC,
    PrintedByCustomerUserID
) VALUES (
    @ItemID, 
    @ConsignmentID,
    @CountryCreateDate, 
    @Reference, 
    @Packaging, 
    @Weight, 
    @WeightCubic, 
    @Length, 
    @Width, 
    @Height, 
    @seqNumber, 
    @DatePrinted, 
    @ad_Excess, 
    @Price_Cost, 
    @Price_Other, 
    @Price_OtherTypeID, 
    @FailedReason,
    @PackedInCustomID, 
    @UpdateDateUTC,
    @PrintedByCustomerUserID
)
```

Comment: ?? Erm. Explanation of your comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change date format:
try 20130524 instead of 24/05/2013

SQL server considers the format your date is in to be ambiguous, because some countries do DD/MM and others do MM/DD, accepted formats are listed here: [Date and Time Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141005.aspx).
I typically go with 'YYYYMMDD', but dashes are fine in there.

Edit:  Additionally, the NUMERIC data type cannot accept a blank string. You'll have to choose a different data type for Price_Cost and Price_Other fields or feed them a '0' instead of empty string ''.

Comment: This seems like more of a comment then a answer. I will attempt it.

Comment: How would you suggest doing that?

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: Server side. Above is the json it returns. 

I should be able to figure it out.

Comment: That's a really unhelpful error message, ay?  Can you isolate the field that's causing the failure by inserting test values into one field at a time?

Comment: In all the other objects `Price_*` is not null, it appears that these are the problems

Comment: It was those fields. I checked if they were null or whitespace, ifso I set them to -1 and the process completed

Comment: Didn't realise numeric couldn't be given an empty string. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in SqlCeDataAdapter select command use .ToString() Method after datetime like this format :

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "', 102)";
```